# Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new in Selenium. I'm using `FirefoxDriver()`. So, basically when i run my program. It opens an external firefox browser, So when i close that firefox browser. my program terminates and says `Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.`

But How to make my program run, After closing browser it should suppose to run and show on console program? Is that possible? Please let me know.

*Surely, help would be appreciated!*

Comment: The whole purpose of selenium is to start a browser, execute the actions that are programmed and test if the outcome is as expected. Your question doesn't make sense. Of course it cannot work when you close the browser window.

Comment: So, How can i achieve this process without using HtmlUnitDriver.. I'm a big fan of Selenium IDE ..So it helps me better to solve id, name or xpath problem.

Comment: Why do you close the browser ? Just leave it open !

Comment: Just run it in a VM where it does not bother you.

Comment: Check whether you are closing the driver in your script,before any method trying to reach some element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();`.
This does not open any external browser.

Comment: No, I've an issue.. due to javascripts.. So, I want to run it first with Firefox.. After that i want to close it automatically and want to run the task in console log. That's it!